# Can you give me the meaning of these two sentences

Tags: meaning

From [The Gun Club's song "John Hardy"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3HrJnPRwxMs) off the album *Miami*:

> **He's been the death of many, a poor man**

and

> Who's gonna kiss your rosy red cheek
> **It's gonna be that steel drivin' man**

What I don't understand is that in the beginning of the song John Hardy killed a man  only one and at the end of the song comes "he has been the death of many" which means he killed more than one person

Comment: I don't know why all the online sources I can find for these lyrics have a comma between ***many*** and ***a poor man***. There's no question that comma is ***syntactically invalid***, regardless of whether in the *actual* rendition there's a detectable pause at that point (as there is between ***many*** and ***a poor boy*** in [*The House of the Rising Sun*](https://genius.com/The-animals-the-house-of-the-rising-sun-lyrics)). Perhaps the John Hardy orthography is erroneously repeating the comma that *correctly* appears before ***poor boy*** (no article) at the end of several lines.

Comment: These lines may be from the same song, but they're two separate questions

Answer (score 0):

There's definitely no comma in the idiomatic usage ***many a poor man*** (which is a dated / stylised / poetic alternative to *[he has caused the death of] **many poor men***).

For the second point, ***it*** refers back to ***who*** - it means *that steel drivin' man is the one who will kiss your rosy red cheek.* Where according to [Wikipedia's article on this Johnny Cash song,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Henry_(folklore)) I see that a ***steel-driving man*** means *a man tasked with hammering a steel drill into rock to make holes for explosives to blast the rock in constructing a railroad tunnel.*

Comment: "I've been the death of many a poor boy" suggests not only that he caused the death of many boys but also that he did so one at a time.  He was a serial killer rather than a mass murderer.  There's also the implication that he was convicted of one count of murder.  The other deaths might not have been murder, or might simply have not been prosecuted.

Comment: @GaryBotnovcan: I think you might be "extrapolating by association" (from *many a time*) there. I can't find a written instance, but *Many a good man died at Agincourt* sounds fine to me as a reference to a single occasion when many died "at the same time". Plus I think that Past Perfect itself *(I have seen many people)* implies ***repeatedly, over time*** more strongly than Simple Past *I saw many people*. But I can't see what makes you think there's any implication that "he was convicted of one count of murder [etc., etc.]".

Comment: As OP mentions, the shooting on the West Virginia line is the only death mentioned until near the end of the song.  The intervening line "But, there was no bail allowed for the murderin' man" makes the charge clear.  The stanza containing "many a poor man" also says that he's ready to die, letting us know that the death sentence has already been imposed and he's just waiting for it to be carried out.  Since he's going to be hanged anyway, it hardly matters what he confesses at that point.

Comment: As far as anyone can determine, John Henry was hired as a steel-driver for the C&O Railroad, a wealthy company that was extending its line from the Chesapeake Bay to the Ohio Valley. Steel drivers, also known as a hammer man, would spend their workdays driving holes into rock by hitting thick steel drills or spikes. The hammer man always had a partner, known as a shaker or turner, who would crouch close to the hole and rotate the drill after each blow. https://www.ibiblio.org/john_henry/analysis.html

Comment: I wonder if "many a poor man" is a nod to *House of the Rising Sun* There is a house in New Orleans / 
/ They call the Rising Sun
/ And it's been the ruin of many a poor boy
/ And God, I know I'm one It was the first thing I thought of when I read it.

Comment: @ColleenV, not so much a "nod" as parallel construction, I would imagine. The Wiki article on "Rising Sun" says the lyrics were "known by miners in 1905" with the oldest published version appearing in 1925. "John Hardy" describes events that happened in 1893, and was the discussion of a 1919 *Journal of American Folklore* article. And of course there is the confusion/conflation with "John Henry;" the "steel-drivin' man" lyric is not present all the versions of "John Hardy" that I'm familiar with. See also http://www.bobdylanroots.com/jhardy.html.

Comment: @randomhead Thanks for that - it wasn't clear to me it was a folk song done by a  post punk band, although if I had thought about the lyrics for more than two seconds, it would have been obvious :)